# How to return data as a Postgres tablefrom a program other than Postgres

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I want to return data from my program in the same format as Postgres uses to return rows.

I had imagined a C program providing data in Postgres tabular result set format to a Python program using the Python module psycopg2. But either of these could change as needed. My hypothetical C program will *not* be running inside a Postgres instance (as an extension or otherwise), it will be an independent process. And, likewise, the client need not issue SQL commands to generate the result set. However it will need to be able to parse and present the result set as if it had arrived from Postgres.

Are there any examples of this flow? Or where should I start to look in the Postgres documentation?

Comment: You could re-implement (parts of) [the wire protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol.html), but why? This would be a major undertaking, and you'd need to implement a whole SQL database.

Comment: @Bergi - I want to allow Postgres clients to receive data from a source, other than Postgress. I don't see how I'd need a SQL database to allow this?

Comment: @Bergi - if you know that the wire protocol and the message exchange requires SQL database like features, then that could be the answer here and I would accept that.

Comment: pgbouncer might be a good project to study - you connect to that with psql and can query its config with some (non-sql) commands and receive result-sets.

Comment: @JimmyNJ Well the Postgres clients will send arbitrary SQL commands to your program, and it needs to respond accordingly as if it had evaluated the SQL. This amounts to implementing (a subset of) a database. Even if you only want to support `SELECT` commands and use a custom source for the actual data, you'll still need to parse and process the SQL.

Comment: @Bergi - I just want to be able to reproduce a result set in the same format as Postgres would and deliver it to a client. The client could then use the result set. The client program need not issue SQL commands to generate that result set - in my case they won't. I'll edit the question to make this clearer.

Comment: You mean you just ignore the SQL command and always respond with a predetermined result set regardless? I suppose that would work, but why are you using an SQL client in the first place then?